# While True python script should loop infinite but it only executes once - Monkeyrunner

Tags: python, monkeyrunner

I created simple python script to do infinite loop to test my android app, however it only runs through succesfully once and stops.

```
# Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection('66b6cc0e')

while True:
    device.touch (300, 1750, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
    MonkeyRunner.sleep(3)
    device.touch(742, 1213, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
    MonkeyRunner.sleep(10)
    device.touch(554, 1613, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
    MonkeyRunner.sleep(10)

# Push SEND MESSAGE
device.touch(300, 1750, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
MonkeyRunner.sleep(3)
device.touch(742, 1213, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
MonkeyRunner.sleep(10)
device.touch(554, 1613, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
MonkeyRunner.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Is the `sleep` timing out the `touch` action in the next iteration?

Comment: Also try using `import time
time.sleep(10)`

Comment: An exception in the loop will exit the loop if it is not caught.

Answer (score 0):

You should have each of the commands within a `try` (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html). It's not preferable to have a bare except (i.e. a catch-all except), but you can try it for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which is almost a drop in replacement for `monkeyruner` but it is pure python.

I made the changes to your script to show that

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
#from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

import re
import sys
import os

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient


# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
#device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection('66b6cc0e')

kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)


while True:
    print "loop"
    device.touch (300, 1750, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
    ViewClient.sleep(3)
    device.touch(742, 1213, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
    ViewClient.sleep(10)
    device.touch(554, 1613, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
    ViewClient.sleep(10)

# Push SEND MESSAGE
device.touch(300, 1750, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
ViewClient.sleep(3)
device.touch(742, 1213, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
ViewClient.sleep(10)
device.touch(554, 1613, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
ViewClient.sleep(10)
```

Also, you can take advantage of [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) and automatically generate this kind of scripts (or even unittests) just by point and clicking on the UI.